# VScode + git: does not checkout submodules

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-submodules, git-clone, git-checkout

I try to use VScode as git-ui. The problem starts when using submodules.

If I switch to a branch all submodule-folders are empty and submodules are not recognized.

It seams that VScode doesn't perform a recursive checkout of branches. How do I activate it?

I tried using the built-in capabilities and `git graph` for switching branches but non of them are working.

All submodule destination folders are added/removed by switching - but they're empty.

Settings activated:

```
Detect Submodules: true
Detect Submodules Limit: 9999
```